# Yii - Gii module does support foreign relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, gii

I m new in Yii i want to know about the gii does it support for relationship for tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Gii will create relations for MyISAM tables if you include a format like the following in the comment of the referenced columns:

`CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (name_of_this_field) REFERENCES related_table_name(related_field_name)`